# Select query result into new column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add the result of a Select query into a new column. I have tried the following and it works but all the rows are Null. The Select query itself works. The column `Occupation_Proper` is an ENUM column created by Updating Select queries from another column if that is somehow affecting it (I hope that makes sense).

```
INSERT INTO incidentdatatwo(Occupation_ABCD)
SELECT `Occupation_Proper` 
FROM incidentdatatwo 
WHERE `Shift` LIKE 'A' OR `Shift` = 'B' OR `Shift` = 'C' OR `Shift` = 'D';
```

Comment: And Occupation_Proper uses the same enum?

Comment: Yes I added the column name Occupation_ABCD as ENUM with elements matching that of Occupation _Proper ENUM

Comment: Can you show us more of the table structure? And am I correct in understanding that you want to create a bunch of new rows in the table that will just have a single value in that one column? Because that seems like an odd goal to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Query like this to set a new Column:

```
UPDATE `incidentdatatwo`
    SET `Occupation_ABCD` = `Occupation_Proper`
WHERE `Shift` LIKE 'A' OR `Shift` = 'B' OR `Shift` = 'C' OR `Shift` = 'D';
```

or this without LIKE

```
UPDATE `incidentdatatwo`
    SET `Occupation_ABCD` = `Occupation_Proper`
WHERE `Shift` IN('A','B','C','D');
```

Comment: (Assuming we're using a case insensitive collation)

Comment: This Answer works, but it also doubles all of the rows for some reason, so I have a new column with the query result in it that lines up with the rest of the data rows, which is perfect, but then I have a whole bunch of rows after that are null in all columns.

Comment: @Sherri - Unfortunately I don't understand what you mean. An update never inserts new rows. Could you please post an example